# I have a Nuxt 2 application and I want a method to be executed only once. What are possible ways to do it?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs2

I have a method in my Nuxt 2 application which basically does the setup of a third party tool. So I want to execute it only once. What are possible ways to do it.